# So I have to put my localized ressource files into English.lproj, Italian.lproj (etc.) folders?

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm confused because this isn't done through xcode. I must find the project folder in finder and then really move files into those *.lproj folders. Is that correct? Or is there a way to see those *.lproj folders in Xcode like Groups and then just drag&drop the files in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get Info on the file you wish to localize.
2. Click the General tab in the window that appears.
3. Click the Make File Localizable button at the bottom of that tab view.
4. Interact further with the interface as needed.

After you make a file localizable, Xcode treats the file itself as if it were a folder. There will be a disclosure arrow next to its name in the Group Tree that you can turn down to reveal all the file's existing localizations.